# Why New keyword (Constructor) gives StackOverFlowError?

Tags: java

In the given below code, it looks like there should be `HeapMemoryOverFlowError` because we are creating object inside object, but it gives `StackOverflowError`.

```
public class JavaConcepts {
    JavaConcepts jc = new JavaConcepts();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new JavaConcepts();     
    }
}
```

Exception in thread "main" `java.lang.StackOverflowError`

```
at Java.JavaConcepts.<init>(JavaConcepts.java:5)
at Java.JavaConcepts.<init>(JavaConcepts.java:5)
at Java.JavaConcepts.<init>(JavaConcepts.java:5)
at Java.JavaConcepts.<init>(JavaConcepts.java:5)
```

Comment: why do you have `JavaConcepts jc = new JavaConcepts();` before `main` ?

Comment: Because of recursion and Stack is getting filled  before heap.

Comment: This object is rather small - just one reference, so it doesn't take much memory. But each level of recursion adds a stackframe. You just run out of stack before you run out of heapspace. Make it large by adding a huge array or something, and you'll see an `OutOfMemoryError` before the `StackOverflowError`. (at least if the array is initialized "above"/before the reference to the instance triggering recursion)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
JavaConcepts jc = new JavaConcepts();
```

That `jc` is an instance variable, which means there's one of them per instance of the JavaConcepts  class. That variable is initialized at when an instance of JavaConcepts is instantiated.

So, trace what happens when you do `new JavaConcepts()`. That creates a new instance of JavaConcepts, which in turn initializes that `jc` variable. To do that, it creates yet another instance of JavaConcepts, which in turn needs to initialize yet another `jc`. This goes on and on, with each `new JavaConcepts()` initialization happening in a new stack frame. Eventually you run out of stack frames, and you get a StackOverflowError.

Visually:

```
    new JavaConcepts():
     jc = new JavaConcepts();
       jc = new JavaConcepts();
         jc = new JavaConcepts();
           jc = new JavaConcepts();
             ...
               (StackOverflowError)
```

Comment: That means at the time of object creation, It create stack frame like method?

Comment: That's correct. You can effectively think of the constructor as a sort of static method for most purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Explanation: In this program, the main() method invokes JavaConcepts()  method. JavaConcepts() method recursively calls itself. This implementation will cause  JavaConcepts() method to be invoked infinite number of times. In this circumstance, JavaConcepts() method will be added to thread’s stack frame infinite number of times. Thus, after a few thousand iterations, thread’s stack size limit would be exceeded. Once stack size limit is exceeded, it will result in  StackOverflowError